# textarea doesn't render correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to do a text counter for a textarea elem.

at first it work as i wished.

[image: its initial status]

I can delete and add character, and it works just fine.

[image: its counting status]

the bugs is when i select all text and delete all, somehow the textarea render without border.

[image]

[image: bug status]

I look through the javascript, found out that, when i delete all, it trigger piece of code to set counter

```
counter_elem.children('.text-count').text(count);
```

and then textarea will not render correctly, but if i comment this code out, it rendered ok.

Style computed form chrome:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
flex-direction: column;
float: left;
font-family: 'Lantinghei SC', 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Hiragino Sans GB', 华文细黑, STHeiti, 微软雅黑, 'Microsoft YaHei', SimHei, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 100px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
outline-color: rgb(86, 90, 92);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
resize: none;
text-align: start;
text-indent: 0px;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-property: border-color;
transition-timing-function: ease;
white-space: pre-wrap;
width: 800px;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: break-word;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Try to share all the relavant  code / demo to help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but it fix the problem

this is the working piece of code:

```
<textarea class="textarea-control work-content" placeholder="录入一条日常工作内容" id="id_work_content_1"></textarea>
```

this is the bug code:

```
<textarea class="textarea-control left work-content" placeholder="录入一条日常工作内容" id="id_work_content_1"></textarea>
```

this only different is the left, which make textarea float left. so in this case, if its not float left, it just working fine. so there is something not compatible with floating..